# counting conditionally formatted cells in excel

Tags: excel, counting, conditional-formatting, vba

Thank you very much for looking into my issue.

Basically I've got a dashboard that I have conditionally formatted - depending on what value is returned to that cell will be if the cell turns red or remains white/unshaded. I have a series of rows at the top of the dashboard that need to total the number of red cells under each column (so H8 sums the total # of red cells in the range H10:H21).

I have attempted to write a VB Macro to count the cells. The function is called with `=CountRed(Range:Range)`, so in my previous example cell H8 `=CountRed(H11:H21)`.

The problem I have is that the macro does not return the **correct number** of red cells. (It will return 5 when there are 3, for example.) I also have no idea why my function isn't dynamic; Using both `Application.Volatile` and `Application.Volatile(True)` doesn't change a thing.

```
Function CountRed(MyRange As Range)
 Dim iCount As Integer
 Application.Volatile
 iCount = 0
 For Each cell In MyRange
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22 Then
        iCount = iCount + 1
    End If
 Next cell
 CountRed = iCount
End Function
```

All formatted cells are the same shade of red (22).

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: What is the rule used for the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the countif function.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx

You may need to reproduce the conditional formatting logic into the if condition of this function, but that should be pretty straight forward. Post some more information about the sheet & conditional formatting rules if you'd like help with that.

Comment: So we'll just work with Column H here. 

First counted row in column H would be row 13; Cell H13. If Cell Value is between `=0` and `=0.19`, No color for the background. If Cell Value is between `=0.2` and `=1`, Cell color needs to be Red. (RGB Value 255, 124, 128).

Each Row has separate conditional formatting paramaters, but they all share the same color red. The value is also pulled from a VLOOKUP function; it's not a manually-entered value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 22 Then
```

instead

```
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22 Then
```

Note, that accordingly to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814%28v=office.15%29.aspx) `DisplayFormat` property does not work in user defined functions if you call them directly from the sheet. But if you will call it from macro, it works:

```
Sub test()
   MsgBox CountRed(Range("C1:C12"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex=22 Then` gives me a #VALUE! Error.

Answer (score -1):

The CELL function may be the answer you need.

[CELL(info_type,reference)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/cell-HP005209008.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211)

One of the info_type's is format.  While it doesn't cover all types of formatting, it covers a broad enough set so that it may suit your need.

It cann pick up whether it's formatted for currency, or is colored, or if has parentheses.  It can pick up left, right, centered, filled text.

It cannot pick up background color, font type/weight/slant.